# Real time console app that triggers everytime it receives new email?

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

I have an email parser application in C# that uses Exchange Web Service where it retrieves incoming emails from the exchange account. Is it possible to have it run real time in the background? Whenever an email arrives, it automatically does its job without me having to click it every time or using a task scheduler. The first plan is task scheduler which I set to run every 5 minutes but I need a more efficient way as this app will receive heaps of emails which will then send a reply back to the sender.

Let me know if I missed some information or if my question is too vague.

Edit:

I did what L-Three suggested but... (please read my reply to BugFinder). The program must only trigger if there is an incoming email. Looping is consuming too much of CPU usage. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @L-Three Thanks. Going to check this out.

Comment: Why not run it as a service?

Comment: @BugFinder As much as possible, it shouldn't consume much cpu usage since the main computer has other running applications which run 24/7. I just did what L-Three suggested but I was told (my boss) that the app should only trigger when there's an email (like there's a listener), not looping which is what Quartz is doing. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I know under outlook you can trigger it when items arrive - I havent directly played with ews but Id imagine you can do the same.

Comment: @BugFinder Actually, I am using Outlook for my exchange account. I just don't have idea how to connect it with my console app like when there's a new email, the program will trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for EWS Push Notifications (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx)

If you google for this term, you will find some sample programs, eg http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73834/EWS-Mail-Notifier.

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out.